# What is the role of AppSettingsReader in MSDN example?

Tags: c#, .net, msdn

I was reading the MSDN page [AppSettingsReader.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e6sbcd(v=vs.110).aspx?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader.GetValue)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) for more information about that. There was an example, I could not figure out the role of `AppSettingsReader` in it. Can anyone tell me what was happened there.

MSDN Example:

```
static void DisplayAppSettings()
{

    try
    {

        AppSettingsReader reader = new AppSettingsReader();


        NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

        for (int i = 0; i < appSettings.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key : {0} Value: {1}",
              appSettings.GetKey(i), appSettings[i]);
        }

    }
    catch (ConfigurationErrorsException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[DisplayAppSettings: {0}]", e.ToString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example code instantiates an `AppSettingsReader` object but does nothing with it.  You can remove that line and nothing would change.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example `AppSettingsReader` is an unused variable. `AppSettingsReader` is used to read app settings from config files. You can find an example on this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader(v=vs.110).aspx)